# Name of a set in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, terminology

What is the name of the set

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{supp}\;u_j\subset\left\lbrace q\in\mathbb{R}^{d}, \frac{1}{2}\le |q|\le 3\right\rbrace.
\end{align*}

For $d=2$ we say an annulus. And for $d\ge 3$ what is its name?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_shell

Comment: its name is shell for only $d=3$?

Comment: No, the name communicates this in any dimension.

Comment: ok thank you very much